# Add data from JSON in existing Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to add a new row at the top of my existing dataframe (df_PRED). Data are coming from a json. The keys of the json (df_NEW) have exactly the same naming like the columns in the existing dataframe.

```
df_NEW = pd.read_json(dataJSON, lines=True) 
df_PRED[-1] = df_NEW
```

Error: *Wrong number of items passed 36, placement implies 1*

What's going wrong? Thank you for your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate `df_PRED` and `df_NEW`:

```
df_PRED = pd.concat([df_NEW,df_PRED])
```